# Why does Zeiss manufacture only manual focus lenses?

Tags: lens, manual-focus, zeiss

I've heard that Zeiss's quality is very good/great but I'm also curious if it has anything to do with the "manual focus only".

I have read [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/why-buy-an-expensive-manual-focus-lens) but it only partly addresses my question. Is it a company policy or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is one of the [lens design compromises](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/is-there-development-in-the-world-of-lenses) they have chosen to make. While I don't think anyone can know for sure the reasons behind that decision, I can think of several likely ones:

- Zeiss's own most successful cameras are [rangefinders](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/zeiss-.html), which do not auto focus. These are the only cameras they [still make today](http://lenses.zeiss.com/photo/en_DE/products/ikon/zeiss_ikon_camera.html).
- MF lenses avoid any complication from integration with an AF system, keeping the lenses smaller.
- Major SLR companies do not license their lens mounts. Companies like Sigma and Tamron reverse engineer the electronic communication protocols. Making an all-manual lens avoids this need — although recent Zeiss lenses do feature electronic coupling for aperture.
- It makes a niche, since lenses designed for MF are usually better for that purpose than those designed for AF. Good MF lenses have a long "focus throw" — you turn the focus ring a large amount to make a difference, allowing fine adjustments. AF lenses, on the other hand, are designed for smaller movements to optimize AF speed.

Answer (score 9):

It probably has as much to do with the fact that they're an OEM lens maker for Sony as anything else. Yes, **Zeiss does make autofocus lenses** for DSLRs, but they're co-branded for the Sony (Minolta/Konica Minolta) system (which is why I cringe every time somebody says there are no "professional" lenses in the Sony lineup).

All of the following are made in Sony α (Minolta A) mounts:

- 24mm/2.0 Distagon T*
- 85mm/1.4 Planar T*
- 135mm/1.8 Sonnar T*
- 16-35mm/2.8 Vario-Sonnar T*
- 16-80mm/3.5-4.5 DT Vario-Sonnar T*
- 24-70mm/2.8 Vario-Sonnar T*

(The 16-80mm lens is designated "DT" and is for APS-C sensors.)

You may see OEM manufacturers making gear for other systems occasionally (notably Tokina, whose agreement with Pentax allows their co-creations to be marketed for other mounts), but there's a pretty good chance that the agreement between Sony and Zeiss doesn't allow them to sell autofocus lenses for competing mounts.

Comment: OEM? Hmm, I was always under the impression that Zeiss licensed their name to Sony, but did not manufacture. Surely they do not make all those tiny camcorder and P&S lenses?

Comment: The designs are licensed for the all-in-ones, but take a look at the lenses for the **α**. It's not just the lens design, or even the lens elements -- the barrels and collars are also pure Carl Zeiss. They're made in a satellite factory in Japan, but by Zeiss.

Comment: I think they're _all_ actually made by Cosina.